# Drag and drop on scrollable div

Tags: jquery, css, treeview

I have 2 divs, left and a right div, the left div contains a treeview and the right div contains a grid. I can drag items into the treeview from the grid, the treeview has code to expand the treeview when I hover over a node.

As the tree explands a scrollbar is present due to the size of the treeview - when I drag an item into the treeview which is fully expanded It doesnt let me drag all the way to the bottom, the problem is that when I drag the scroll bar doeesnt scroll, so any items currently which I would normally need to use the scrollbar to see - it doesnt let me drag on the treeview down the way enough to see those items.

The left div has the following:-

```
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 800px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, you can still scroll using the mouse wheel.  As the person designing the widget, I suggest adding a hotspot (div with javascript bound to mousemove event) a few pixels high above and below the tree.  In the mousemove event, scroll the tree either up or down (depending on which hotspot is being hovered) - the user will then be able to scroll the tree by wiggling the mouse over the hotspot.

If the object being dragged intercepts the mousemove event (quite likely), then you'll have to add some code to check whether the object is being dragged above or below the tree, and scroll the tree accordingly (at an appropriate speed).  That code will have to be on an element that can tell where the mouse is - possibly the body element.